# Database of labeled hyperspectral imagery

Tags: data, multi-band, hyperspectral-sensor

Are there any datasets of hyperspectral imagery that can be used for AI training and classification, comparable to ImageNet? The Universitat de Valencia has one listed on their [site](http://isp.uv.es/data_rs.html), HyperLabelMe, but it seems to have been taken down.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [SpaceNet](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/spacenet/); the idea is the same as ImageNet, but for remote sensing data (not hyperspectral though).

Comment: @LoïcDutrieux I'm specifically looking for hyper- or multi-spectral imagery.

Comment: Then SpaceNet might suit your needs as it uses multi-spectral worldview data.

Comment: I need hyperspectral images in medical field. Can I get the dataset link

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128178)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128178)